# Can I create mutilple database structure in core data?

Tags: ios, core-data

Now , I was using fmdb in my app , and every user account got a dbfile which is used to create the db of his'own (each db contains the same structure tables, and the tables contains the user specific data) If I use core-data, can I do the same thing?

Comment: Yes, just name the persistent store based on the username

Comment: can you find me some examples or documents?thanks

Comment: Show the code where you set up your persistent store

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, simply use different URLs for them (If the structure is exactly the same it's easy). Something like this should work.

```
NSURL *storeURL = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] URLByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.sqlite", username]];
```